# VB : How to destroy an object?

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I need help to destroy an object in VB.

**Here's the context** : My object is created when the application starts. When the user requests for my application closing, it handles it and destroys a C++ object *via* a DLL.

**Here's the problem** : This object does not seem to be destroyed at application closing.

In consequence, as I restart the application for the second time, the C++ object is destroyed twice. As I restart the application for the third time, the C++ is destroyed thrice, *e caetera*.

So, I need a way to destroy this VB object or to tell it not to handle the application close anymore after the application has effectively closed.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Regards,

Vick91

Comment: what about MyObj=Nothing   ?

Comment: Is is a COM object?  If so, you need to call `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject()`

Comment: @romulus001 : Thanks for your help. It worked !

Comment: @ChrisDunaway : It was not a COM object, but thanks anyway.